# Counting values from HTML radio buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, checked

I have a form/questionnaire where the user must choose various options in HTML.
Javascript will then add up all the options; there are more forms that will be added up to create a grand total.
I know that I need to use parseInt and various if statements:
if option 1 is selected, return value
if option 2 is selected, return value
and so on..

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="age" id= "age1" value="0" checked> 1-25<br>
<input type="radio" name="age" id= "age2" value="5"> 26-40<br>
<input type="radio" name="age" id= "age3" value="8"> 41-60<br>
<input type="radio" name="age" id= "age4" value="10"> 60+<br>
```

Javascript:

```
calculateAge () {
    var age = parseInt (document.getElementById('age1').value)
    if (age = checked)  return age;
    console.log('age')
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? What do you get with your code?

Comment: You can simply let the appropriate CSS selector do the job of finding the checked elements (see my answer). This way you don't have to check each and every radio button whether it is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do a **sum** over all selected radio button **values** on **click** of e.g. a `button`.

The core of this apporach is to **only select those radio buttons which are checked** `input[type=radio]:checked`. If you have those, it's easy to use `Array.prototype.reduce` to boil that collection down to the sum.

```js
calc.addEventListener('click', sumToVariable)

var sum;

function sumUp() {
  let sum = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked')]
    .reduce(
      (acc, val) => acc + Number(val.value)
      , 0
    )
  result.textContent = sum;
  return sum;
}

function sumToVariable() {
  sum = sumUp();
  console.log(sum);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}

#result:not(:empty)::before {
  content: "Sum of selected options: ";
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="age" id="age1" value="0" checked> 1-25<br>
<input type="radio" name="age" id="age2" value="5"> 26-40<br>
<input type="radio" name="age" id="age3" value="8"> 41-60<br>
<input type="radio" name="age" id="age4" value="10"> 60+<br>
<hr />
<input type="radio" name="age2" id="age10" value="0" checked> 1-25<br>
<input type="radio" name="age2" id="age20" value="5"> 26-40<br>
<input type="radio" name="age2" id="age30" value="8"> 41-60<br>
<input type="radio" name="age2" id="age40" value="10"> 60+<br>
<hr />
<button type="button" id="calc">Calc</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

You could as well do the same on change of a radio button:

```js
radiobuttons.addEventListener('change', () => {
  result.textContent = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked')]
    .reduce(
      (acc, val) => acc + Number(val.value)
      , 0
    )
  }
)
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}

#result:not(:empty)::before {
  content: "Sum of selected options: ";
}
```

```html
<div id="radiobuttons">
  <input type="radio" name="age" id="age1" value="0" checked> 1-25<br>
  <input type="radio" name="age" id="age2" value="5"> 26-40<br>
  <input type="radio" name="age" id="age3" value="8"> 41-60<br>
  <input type="radio" name="age" id="age4" value="10"> 60+<br>
  <hr />
  <input type="radio" name="age2" id="age10" value="0" checked> 1-25<br>
  <input type="radio" name="age2" id="age20" value="5"> 26-40<br>
  <input type="radio" name="age2" id="age30" value="8"> 41-60<br>
  <input type="radio" name="age2" id="age40" value="10"> 60+<br>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: this first option is great and it works, but i will need to output certain messages depending on the result. as it stands, i dont know how to use that result to do this. can it be turned into a variable?

Comment: Sure, just return the result of the reduce function. I'll edit the first variant.

Answer (score 0):

```
age = checked
```

cannot work, because age is an int, and a single equal sign is not used for comparison. Also checked is a property and not a comparable. You could use it like so:

```
function calculateAge () {
  let age = parseInt (document.getElementById('age1').value)
  if (document.getElementById('age1').checked)  return age;
  console.log('age')
}
```

Also you didnt ask a question, assuming you want to know why there is nothing returned.

Comment: apologies for the lack of question. thanks, i believe this is what I was looking for.